# Taking one to many difference Between Groups in Tidy Data

Tags: r, tidyr, tidyverse

I have a tidy data set similar to the hear-rate example in [Introducing tidyr blog post](https://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/), but I have an additional "placebo" group under the drug which I can construct like this

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
messy <- data.frame(
  name = c("Wilbur", "Petunia", "Gregory"),
  a = c(67, 80, 64),
  b = c(56, 90, 50),
  p = c(60, 70, 60)    # this is the new 'placebo' drug
)
tidy <- messy %>% 
        gather(drug, heartrate, a:p)
```

Assuming I start with tidy data, my goal is to create a new variable called "diff.p" which is the difference between the observation for each drug and the placebo. The results should look like this

```
tidy$diff.p <- c(7,10,4,-4,20,-10,0,0,0)
tidy
```

It seems like `ave` and/or `mutate` might be good paths to the solution (or perhaps constructing a new data frame?), but I need some additional guidance on best practice.

Comment: FWIW statistically this isn't a great idea. It would be better to include p in your model.

Comment: I don't know very much about statistics, maybe you could point me to some references that elaborate on what you mean by "better to include p in your model". Thanks!

Comment: Include p as one of the terms in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `dplyr` chain, you can do this by grouping by `name` and then subtracting `heartrate[drug=="p"]` from `heartrate`:

```
tidy = tidy %>% group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(diff.p2 = heartrate - heartrate[drug=="p"])
```

> ```
>      name  drug heartrate diff.p diff.p2
>    <fctr> <chr>     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
> 1  Wilbur     a        67      7       7
> 2 Petunia     a        80     10      10
> 3 Gregory     a        64      4       4
> 4  Wilbur     b        56     -4      -4
> 5 Petunia     b        90     20      20
> 6 Gregory     b        50    -10     -10
> 7  Wilbur     p        60      0       0
> 8 Petunia     p        70      0       0
> 9 Gregory     p        60      0       0
> ```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping to be able to do, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you can do this fairly easily with a second `tidy`:

```
tidy2 <- messy %>%
  mutate(a = a-p, b = b-p, p = 0) %>%
  gather(drug, diff.p, a:p)

left_join(tidy, tidy2, by = c("name", "drug"))
#      name drug heartrate diff.p
# 1  Wilbur    a        67      7
# 2 Petunia    a        80     10
# 3 Gregory    a        64      4
# 4  Wilbur    b        56     -4
# 5 Petunia    b        90     20
# 6 Gregory    b        50    -10
# 7  Wilbur    p        60      0
# 8 Petunia    p        70      0
# 9 Gregory    p        60      0
```

Comment: This seems to be a pretty good approach to address the problem for the particular example I provided, but if I had started with a tidy data set, I would have to `spread` then apply this function. In addition, it doesn't look like it would scale very if I had drugs a,b,c,d,e,....etc.that I needed to compare.

Comment: Alright, your point is technically salient, but you never implied in your question that you may be *starting* with tidy data. What in your question should have indicated to me to make this assumption? And what indication do you have that this will not scale well, given that your problem starts with un-tidy data?

Comment: Good point. I've edited the question so there won't be any confusion for future readers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(messy), id.var = "name", variable.name = "drug", 
 value.name = "heartrate")[, diff.p2 := heartrate - heartrate[drug=="p"]][]
#      name drug heartrate diff.p2
#1:  Wilbur    a        67       7
#2: Petunia    a        80      10
#3: Gregory    a        64       4
#4:  Wilbur    b        56      -4
#5: Petunia    b        90      20
#6: Gregory    b        50     -10
#7:  Wilbur    p        60       0
#8: Petunia    p        70       0
#9: Gregory    p        60       0
```